# Difference between Bash's stdin and Node's stdin stream

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, stdin

I am trying to `npm login` to private registry using a Node script. In bash, the following command runs like a charm:

```
echo -e "testuser\ntestpassword\ntest@test.test\n" \
    | npm login --registry=http://localhost:4873/
```

However, I failed to call `npm` the same way using Node script. I tried:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const childProcess = spawn("npm", ["login", "--registry=http://localhost:4873"]);

childProcess.stdin.write("testuser\ntestpassword\ntest@test.test\n");
childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
childProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

The `npm` process receives Username but stops when asking for Password. I do not understand what is the difference between passing the `"testuser\ntestpassword\ntest@test.test\n"` string to the process using bash or using Node stream. Also, a working implementation would be nice.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the Node version writing real linefeeds or the digraph `\n` to standard input?

Comment: @chepner `\n` is parsed into newline as part of string literals in JS.